# Moq TargetParameterCountException with lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, nunit, moq

I have strange problem: when I use mu repository stub I get strange exception:

System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException

Creating stub (in a test method):

```
var repositoryStub = new Mock<IRepository<User>>();
repositoryStub.Setup(m => m.FindAll(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User,bool>>>())).Returns(TestGlobals.TestUsers.AsQueryable<User>);
```

Interface:

```
IQueryable<T> FindAll(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression);
```

And on every call to *FindAll* throws that error :( I'm mocking in that fashion in many other places, but now I can't find source of that strange problem :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have missed a pair of parenthesis after the `AsQueryable` call:

```
repositoryStub.Setup(m => m.FindAll(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User,bool>>>())).Returns(TestGlobals.TestUsers.AsQueryable<User>());
```

The `Returns` method has multiple overloads and most of them takes a Func and without the parenthesis it uses one of these overloads and because you haven't specified a parameter that's why it throws an exception.

Comment: The `Returns` call in my own code today had the wrong number of type arguments, even though the `Setup` call had the correct number. This post saved me a lot of trouble.